# Core Data: refreshing tableview when switching tabs in tab bar

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nspredicate

I'm using core data for a tab bar + navigation controller prototype app, with one entity: Event.

So I have two tabs, the past and the present. I'm using nsfetchedresultscontroller and nspredicate to filter the data into their respective table views.

now here is where i'm having a problem, when i create a new date, it shows up in the present table view like i expect, but as time goes by the event stays there past the date, and never moves to the past table view. The only way i can achieve this is just launching the app from scratch, killing the background view.

I've tried to install reloadData call to table view in view will appear. That doesn't work.

I tried to use [tableview reloadData] when the app launches from background too. but that doesn't work too.

I can't think of anything else, hoping you guys could help.

[Edit]

I just figured out how to do it! I tried to download the sample code i thought i uploaded to github, but looks like there is no file there. I cant figure out how to upload the project up there.

anyway, the thing to do to achieve this is in the view did appear, just place in the entire fetch request that's in the fetched results controller (without the fetched results controller variables) with the predicate. now if the moment you switch views, the entire data is updated and filtered!

Hope this helps anyone else looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: Add code so that users can look into it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm, if you have already tried reload data, these others could be possible problems:

- be sure the cache is consistent with the predicate. If in table
  controller you use a cache, and the table is populated with something
  like `entityDate = myCalculatedDate` then the predicate could be different,
  and you need to delete cache first. I think you could try to set
  `cache:nil` to see if this is the problem.
- for updating table, especially with new inserted rows, or moved rows
  to different index you need to implement the fetched controller
  delegate
- **[EDIT]** also if I remember well, I am not sure if standard
  mechanism of `viewWillAppear/dissappear` works as expected with Tab Bar,
  probably there's some delegate to implements, but it's just a
  guessing !

this what I can guess without seeing the code.